# Which is faster way to encrypt/decrypt data in c#?

Tags: c#, encryption

I used following function but its take 50 sec to 1 min to decrypt 1100 records of contact us form. So it's take around 1 min time when I filter something. Because I need to encrypt whole data then I fire filter query in C#.

This is the Encrypt method:

```
public static string Encrypt(string encryptString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptString))
        return encryptString;

    string EncryptionKey = "---";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(encryptString);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] 
        { 
            0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 
        });

        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            encryptString = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return encryptString;
}
```

And this is my Decrypt method:

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
        return cipherText;

    string EncryptionKey = "---";
    cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] 
        {
            0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76
        });

        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: If you do not cipher, it is instant. Assuming that does not count, a simple substitution cipher should be ridiculously fast. No? Ok, talk me about security, because otherwise, that is the answer. Hint: You need constraints to optimize. PS: /dev/null is web scale.

Comment: There's always a conflict between security and usability. The real question should be. Is the security worth the performance hit. encryption and decryption is always going to be slower than storing plain-text.

Comment: Problem is that you encrypt each record separately. This cripples  security of encryption (data entropy is greatly reduced) and I'm sure is also source performance issue.

Comment: @MarekR how we can encrypt/decrypt in bulk then?

Comment: Most production database systems (like SQL Server) now have excellent options for encryption (Always Encrypted, `ENCRYPTBYKEY`), as does the OS itself (TDE, `ProtectedData`) and you should look into using those before rolling your own. Implementing encryption to make it both secure and usable is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: The slowest part is your call to Rfc2898DeriveBytes, which is designed to be slow in order to be more secure by hindering brute force attacks. If you always use the same key, only create one instance in advance.

Comment: @DavidG - 50 seconds sounds like a clear performance problem, which takes most of that rant away.

Comment: @JeroenMostert SQL server encryption will return decrypted data when I select data from table? Will it take less time then c#?

Comment: Always Encrypted is completely transparent to the application, which is mainly why it's attractive. `ENCRYPTBYKEY` requires that you `DECRYPTBYKEY` (or `DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOASYMKEY`), but you can still make that mostly transparent to your applications. Speed improvements from either method would come from the encryption being symmetric (using a key that is asymmetrically encrypted and stored once), the database server having more power than an office machine and the engine being closer to the data itself (saving network roundtrips).

Comment: Fast is the enemy of secure. Encryption is, by design, slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refactor your code and it takes less than a second to decrypt and encrypt 1000 items.

```
var watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
using (var service = new Cryptography("---"))
{
    var listEncrypt = new List<string>();
    var listPlain = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var encypt = service.Encrypt(i.ToString());
        listEncrypt.Add(encypt);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var plain = service.Decrypt(listEncrypt[i]);
        listPlain.Add(plain);
    }
}
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString());
Console.Read();
```

The idea is to create only one instance of encryptor to encrypt/decrypt the list

```
public class Cryptography : IDisposable
{
    private Aes Encryptor;

    public Cryptography(string key)
    {
        Encryptor = Aes.Create();
        var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, new byte[]
            {
                0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76
            });

        Encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        Encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
    }

    public string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
            return plainText;

        var clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, Encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
            }
            plainText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }

        return plainText;
    }

    public string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
            return cipherText;

        cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
        var cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, Encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
        return cipherText;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Encryptor.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Now it's taking 1 second. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can should remove the PBKDF2 from the loop that goes over the contacts. If you keep using PBKDF2 (the algorithm implemented by the incredibly daftly named `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class) then just ask for 16 bytes and you'll receive a free speedup of 3 times, without any clear implications to security. You can then use an IV consisting of zero bytes.

Note that your salt should however be random. Currently you may leak information on the plaintext: if the first few blocks of two encrypted messages are identical then an attacker will immediately see this from the ciphertext.

I'd strongly advice you to revisit your encryption scheme and if possible hire an expert. The output of PBKDF2 should not be used directly to encrypt contacts in a database.