# Filling dropdown list in code behind takes a lot of time?

Tags: c#

I have this code to fill my `listbox` in my asp.net project.

```
 private void GetAllVendors()
        {
            cmbVendor.Items.Clear();
            IAbstractDBLogic<UserInput, SystemResult> systemProcess = new GetAllVendorsLogic();
            _userInput = new UserInput();
            _systemResult = systemProcess.DoProcess(_userInput);
            _dataTable = _systemResult[typeof(DataTable).FullName] as DataTable;

            foreach (DataRow row in _dataTable.Rows)
            {
                ListItem item = new ListItem()
                {
                    Text = Hasher.DecryptString(row["VendorName"].ToString()),
                    Value = row["VendorID"].ToString()
                };
                cmbVendor.Items.Add(item); 
            }
        }
```

For your information, I have like almost 3000 distinct data in my table. The table I am doing this have 4 column names and in my query to get the `VendorName` is like this

`SELECT VendorID, VendorName FROM VendorInformation_TBL`

As of now, I am testing it and the data processing the 3000 records runs like 60 to 75 seconds.

How can I make this code faster than usual?

Comment: Is it the SELECT query that's slow (have you run it in SSMS or something similar) or the creation of the items from the datarows?

Comment: @sr28 the creation of the datarows is slow.

Comment: In that case it's most likely the way your encrypting and decrypting. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208363/which-is-faster-way-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-c